# How to start docker without affecting host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtual-machine

I am trying to run a docker image from here: http://laradock.io/

One of the problems I got myself into is a series of errors:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: listen: address already in use
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:6379: bind: address already in use
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
...
```

Searching for a solution I found that to fix this I need to kill nginx, mysql, redis etc. on my host to allow docker to take over the ports.

But the main reasom I am trying to use docker (or any VM) is to make the application not use the host but instead use an adress like 192.168.1.5 (assuming that will be the ip address of docker container)

My question is if that is even possible with docker and if yes than what I need to do to maintain 100% separation between host and docker.

Comment: Can you post the command you're running when you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this problem

1. Do not publish ports.  If you don't publish ports then there won't be any conflicts.
2. Publish the ports to something else.  You probably have something like `--publish 443:443`.  This is a conflict because your host machine is already using 443 for something.  You can change that to `--publish 20443:443`.
3. Publish the ports to a specific interface (if possible).  If your host is using port 443 on 192.168.100.101 but not on 127.0.100.102 then you can do `--publish 127.0.100.102:443:443` without conflict.
4. Use `publish-all`.  Instead of `--publish 443:443` use `--publish-all`.  Docker will pick unused ports on your system - guaranteeing no conflict.  You can use either `docker ps` or `docker inspect` to find out what those ports are.

Comment: I think solution #3 is the closest to what I want to use, but I guess it would require to edit `docker-compose.yml` file from laradock (aka editing the application source) and I would like to avoid that.

Is it possible to do seomething like:
`--publish 127.0.100.102:*:*`, so it will map all ports used in config to that one ip?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to use docker-machine vm.

```
# Create machine
docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.10.10.1/24" docker-default

# Export docker .env variables
eval $(docker-machine env docker-default)
```

One issue I found is that I need to use NFS to share the projects folder with the docker machine. 
For that I used following script: https://github.com/adlogix/docker-machine-nfs
I had to modify the file since on linux You cannot have a space after the IP (line 372):

```
exports="${exports}$shared_folder $machine_ip$prop_nfs_config\n"
```

then I could run

```
docker-machine-nfs docker-default -f --nfs-config="(rw,no_subtree_check,crossmnt,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)" \
    --shared-folder=/mnt/projects \
    --shared-folder=/home/hubertnnn/projects
```